# How to wait for a specific manual action using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How to make my script wait for a manual click on a submit button as in below website ?

```
driver.get("http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing?listing_type=sale&search_type=district&property_id=&interest=&distance=1&property_type=&freetext=&districts%5B%5D=&hdb_estate=&maxprice=&maxbed=&minbed=&minsize=&searchbtn=Search")
```

There are alot of chosing option in search box, I want my scraping script wait until I 'm done with chossing all option and then I click submit button SEARCH

Comment: This kinda defeats the point of automating tasks... waiting for manual input. Script the choices and then you won't need to stop.

Comment: but I want to select those options manually, then click the "SEARCH" button to submit,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a breakpoint on the code you want to stop at. Run the script in debug mode (see help files for your IDE), it will break on that point, you do your manual task, and then start the script back up when you are done.

Comment: a good idea, but I want the script wait until i press the button

Comment: What happens when you press the button? Does some element appear or disappear or does the page change, etc? You can put a WebDriverWait with a really long timer that waits for that element or URL change and then continues on.

Comment: when the button is pressed, it create a new URL base on options that we select

Comment: In that case you could use `WebDriverWait` and wait for the URL to contain some string, etc.

Comment: I will try with that approach

Comment: i went with that approach but not use WebDriverWait. i just check if URL changes by placing it in a while loop

Comment: I would suggest you use WebDriverWait and wait until the URL changes. It was built for this purpose and will allow you to still have some sort of time out without having to implement it yourself. You want a timeout or your script might get stuck and never finish.

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver, AbstractEventListener

# My custom event listener
class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):
    clicked = False
    def before_click(self, element, driver):
        print ("Event : before element click()")


    def after_click(self, element, driver):
        print ("Event : after element click()")




# Get an event-firing-web-driver instance
driver = EventFiringWebDriver(webdriver.Chrome(), MyListener())

# Visit a site
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/")

# Find an element
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# Click on element
elem.click()
```

I found this line of codes. It's able to track an button press event
Are there any way to combine this with WebDriverWait()